# Change Outlook appointment series having a starting date in the past

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

When I get involved with a project that is already running the project lead or scrum master forwards an appointment series like daily stand-ups or similar. The series started before I receive the invitation.

Example:

- The series starts on January, 11th 2021 (Monday) and re-occurs every week.
- I receive the invitation on March, 16th 2021 (Tuesday).

When I look into my calendar I will see this appointment in January, February etc. although I didn't participate because I wasn't assigned. To keep my calendar in a way that shows what happened I manually remove those occurrences.

What I want to achieve:

- The invitation enters my inbox.
- `Application_NewMailEx` is triggered and checks for a series like the following.

```vb
(...)
If TypeName(objInboxObject) = "MeetingItem" Then
    Set objAppt = objInboxObject.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)
    If Not objAppt Is Nothing Then
        If objAppt.IsRecurring Then
            Set objRecurrPatt = objAppt.GetRecurrencePattern
            If Not objRecurrPatt Is Nothing Then
(...)
```

**How I can I find out the next future occurrence starting from today (the date I received it)?** In the example this would be March, 22nd 2021. *Especially if the re-occurrence pattern is more complex than in the example.*

I would replace the start date of the series with this calculated date and save the MeetingItem. If I accept it in the normal Outlook window I will have calendar entries in the future and none in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the [RecurrencePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern) object you can find the date of the next occurrence. Then you can use the [RecurrencePattern.GetOccurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.getoccurrence) method which returns a specific instance of the `AppointmentItem` object on the specified date. The `GetOccurrence` method generates an error if no appointment of that series exists on the specified date.

Comment: I'll look into it, but it looks like this is a long and bumpy road. Hoped that someone already did it and has a code snippet to share. Nevertheless, thank you very much for showing me the direction! :-)

Comment: Why do you un-mark answers?